# No sound in Mathematica under Linux

Tags: linux, audio, mathematica

I have a huge set of events in Mathematica that I need to react to, and it's not practical always checking for it, especially since events are randomly distributed in time.
So I wanted to add a simple sound to remind me to go check the event. 
I wanted to use `Beep[]` but I get no results, in fact, I didn't realize till now that Mathematica is making no sounds whatsoever.

I use Debian Squeeze Stable and have no trouble with any other application using sound.

This effects all recent versions (7, 8 and 9) of Mathematica and probably older versions depending on your system's sound set up.

Comment: This has been a problem in Mma ever since they added [sound commands](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SoundAndSonification.html) in version 6. I remember fixing it at the time, but have not bothered in the more recent versions. Try the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mathematica#Sound).

Comment: Should this question be migrated to superuser?

Comment: Unfortunately I still get no sound.

Comment: I'm the original poster on Stackoverflow. Thank you for telling me about this site, I didn't know this one existed.
It's fantastic I could get good use of it.

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15191/2842

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>As far as I know, Mathematica has never really supported sound in Linux.</s> 
The command `Play` was introduced in version 3, 
and the whole sound system overhauled in version 6. 
If you search comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica, 
you'll find questions going back all the way to version 3. 
In version 6, the command `EmitSound` was introduced. 
This now underlies most of the Mathematica sound generation, 
but I couldn't find a quick way to fix/hack it for linux, 
since `EmitSound` does some preprocessing 
(figuring out what types of objects its been given) 
before passing the sound to the frontend to evaluate.

The default sound driver/API used in most linux installs is [ALSA](http://wiki.debian.org/ALSA) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture)). 
It became the default in 2002 in the linux kernel 2.6 
and [OSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_System) was marked as "depreciated" 
(although OSS is still under active development). 
Many Linux distributions now use [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) 
which sits on top of the underlying ALSA sound. 
(Anyone with a better understanding of Linux sound should feel free to edit this!)

Mathematica introduced sound in version 3 (1996) and thus used OSS for its *nix variants. 
This is still the case, despite OSS no longer being the default in almost any Linux variant. 
Knowing this gives us a possible solution: use an OSS emulation layer 
(see, e.g., http://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ).

The simplest is to use an userspace mode emulation and run Mathematica through `aoss`

```
aoss mathematica
```

or the PulseAudio equivalent

```
padsp mathematica
```

The problem with both of these is that it only works with MIDI sounds, 
not with sampled sounds. 
At least this is true on my Ubuntu 10.10 system 
and the linux system of Scott Kruger (of the [WRI Technical Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/) team).
A bug report has been filed on this issue.

Alternatively, you can load the OSS compatibility into your kernel

```
apt-get install alsa-oss
modprobe snd_pcm_oss
modprobe snd_mixer_oss
```

and you can add `snd_pcm_oss` and `snd_mixer_oss` to `/etc/modules` 
to load them at boottime.
These modules are [not readily available in Ubuntu 10.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oss-compat/+bug/659024) 
since they decided to remove the backwards compatibility. 
I can not test the above without recompiling my kernel...

---

Since the above OSS emulation is not currently working perfectly,
here's a couple of quick work-arounds based on some of the discussions I've seen 
(e.g., [a](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/gd9UqsAS-nw/discussion) [b](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/iMeQ8PuZVFE/discussion) [c](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mathematica#Sound)) and rewritten to use default ALSA commands.

For sampled sound, use `aplay`:

```
ALSASound[snd_, "WAV"] := Module[{playCmd = "aplay", soundFileName},
  soundFileName = "/dev/shm/" <> ToString[Unique["MmaSound"]] <> ".wav";
  playCmd = playCmd <> " " <> soundFileName;
  Export[soundFileName, snd, "WAV"];
  Run["(" <> playCmd <> ";" <> "/bin/rm -f " <> soundFileName <> ")&"];]
```

e.g., `ALSASound[Play[Sin[1000 t^2], {t, 0, 1}], "WAV"]`.
You should also be able to `Export` straight onto the appropriate `/dev/snd/` device... 
but I couldn't get that working.

For `midi` use `aplaymidi`. 
For this to work you need some sort of software/hardware midi synth installed. 
I have `timidity` running on port 128. (See [here](http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/media/audio/ad11-MIDI/ar01s05.html) for help)

```
ALSASound[snd_, "MIDI"] := 
 Module[{playCmd = "aplaymidi", port = "128:0", soundFileName},
  soundFileName = "/dev/shm/" <> ToString[Unique["MmaSound"]] <> ".mid";
  playCmd = playCmd <> " -p " <> port <> " " <> soundFileName;
  Export[soundFileName, snd, "MIDI"];
  Run["(" <> playCmd <> ";" <> "/bin/rm -f " <> soundFileName <> ")&"];]
```

e.g., `ALSASound[Sound[SoundNote /@ CharacterRange["A", "G"]], "MIDI"]`

You can now wrap the appropriate `ALSASound` command around any sound object. 
You could also redefine [`Play`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Play.html) to use `ALSASound`:

```
SetOptions[Play, DisplayFunction -> ((ALSASound[#, "WAV"]; #) &)];
```

This is essentially equivalent to setting [$SoundDisplayFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$SoundDisplayFunction.html), 
as recommended by many of the discussions around the internet.
This option setting will play the sound, then output the normal graphics.

```
Play[Sin[1000 t^2], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Play]

but the start/stop buttons will not work, since they are based on [`EmitSound`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EmitSound.html).

To make a simple [`Beep[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Beep.html) equivalent, try

```
ALSABeep[] := Play[Sin[5000 t], {t, 0, .1}, 
                   DisplayFunction -> (ALSASound[#, "WAV"]&)]
```

Finally, if you install the festival text-to-speech 
(or any other [text-to-speech](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TextToSpeech) program), 
then you can replace the Mathematica `Speak` functionality, e.g.,

```
FestivalSpeak[str_String] := (Run["(echo \"" <> str <> "\" | esddsp festival --tts)&"];)
FestivalSpeak[expr_] := FestivalSpeak[SpokenString[expr]]
```

Comment: Simon, this answer did the trick, thank you very much.

Comment: Btw, does anybody know if Mathematica plans to support sound on Linux in the future?
I'd guess that they are specific software where percentage of people using it on Linux is much greater than for most other software.

Comment: @enedene: I asked that question of WRI support today. Hopefully we'll get an answer in the next few days...

Comment: Thank you Simon, you've been helpful.
If you get an answer, please post it here or give a link.

Comment: @enedene: I got a helpful reply from WRI support. See the edit!

Comment: @Simon Thank you for your help once again. I did not get the `Beep[]`, perhaps it's not midi? In any case, solution that you've proposed before did do the job, recompiling my kernel is also not an option.
I hope that in following versions they will use alsa/pulseaudio, for now I'll refine my self for doing to much sound in Mathematica, and for simple sounds I have your proposed solution.

Comment: Is there any way to redefine EmitSound to use ALSA, or does EmitSound use more formats than `midi` and `wav`?

Comment: @bb10g - Maybe you should phrase this as a full question and post it on the [mma.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site. There are a few WRI employees and lots of expert users there who might be able to answer...